# CKEditor: Plugin Button is shown but the command is not working

Tags: ckeditor

first of all, thank you for your support.

I've tried to create my first plugin for CKEditor.
I used the official Tutorial: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample

The Button appears in the Toolbar. But if I click on this, nothing happens.

Here is my Code of plugin.js

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'drmail', {
    icons: 'drmail',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'drmailCommand', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                var now = new Date();
                editor.insertHtml( 'The current date and time is: <em>' + now.toString() + '</em>' );
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'DRmail', {
            label: "E-Mail Adresse hinzufügen",
            command: 'drmailCommand',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: is it showing any error in browser console? did you try placing JS debugger?

Comment: Please provide a working example (jsfiddle.net), otherwise it's really hard to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your Help.

I found it. (The Hint to the JS-Debugger was very good)
I had an old not functional version of the Script in Cache.

Dean